# Why php is throwing error when using dba_open for db4?

Tags: php, apache, gdbm

I am trying to use db4 with php8.x

```
$cachefile = '/etc/cdata/cfile';
$dbh = dba_open($cachefile, "rl", "db4");
```

I am getting the error:

> dba_open(/etc/cdata/cfile.lck): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

What am I doing wrong?

dba_open statement should execute successfully without warnings.
I have changed owner of `/etc/cdata` folder to `www-data:www-data`
(php version 8.2)

Comment: You changed the folder permissions - what about the file itself?

Comment: File will be created by dba_open function, it does not exist already.